# std.net.curl linker errors in Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ld, d

I'm trying to use std.net.curl on 32-bit Ubuntu Linux (11.10 Ocelot) using DMD 2.058.

When I build (`dmd source.d`) I get:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.6.1/../../../../lib/libphobos2.a(curl.o): In function `_D3std3net4curl4Curl19_sharedStaticCtor30FZv':
std/net/curl.d:(.text._D3std3net4curl4Curl19_sharedStaticCtor30FZv+0x6): undefined reference to `curl_global_init'
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.6.1/../../../../lib/libphobos2.a(curl.o): In function `_D3std3net4curl4Curl19_sharedStaticDtor31FZv':
std/net/curl.d:(.text._D3std3net4curl4Curl19_sharedStaticDtor31FZv+0x4): undefined reference to `curl_global_cleanup'
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.6.1/../../../../lib/libphobos2.a(curl_12fd_140.o): In function `_D3std3net4curl4HTTP4Impl6__dtorMFZv':
std/net/curl.d:(.text._D3std3net4curl4HTTP4Impl6__dtorMFZv+0x12): undefined reference to `curl_slist_free_all'
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.6.1/../../../../lib/libphobos2.a(curl_12fd_140.o): In function `_D3std3net4curl4HTTP3dupMFZS3std3net4curl4HTTP':
std/net/curl.d:(.text._D3std3net4curl4HTTP3dupMFZS3std3net4curl4HTTP+0x53): undefined reference to `curl_slist_append'

[snip]
```

I added `-L-lcurl` to my command line (full command: `dmd source.d -L-lcurl`) but I get the exact same result.  I have libcurl4-openssl installed.  I can build a [simple C curl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/simple.html) program on this computer without issue (`gcc simple.c -lcurl`).  I'm not sure where to look from here to figure this out.

*Update:* Here is how the linker is invoked according to `dmd -v`:

```
gcc source.o -o source -m32 -lcurl -Xlinker -L/usr/lib -Xlinker -L/usr/lib64 -Xlinker --no-warn-search-mismatch -Xlinker --export-dynamic -lphobos2 -lpthread -lm -lrt
```

Comment: Try to run with `-v` (`dmd -v source.d -L-lcurl`) to see how the linker is invoked.

Comment: @KennyTM Updated post with information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out if I obtain the linker command through `-v` and reorder it so the `-lcurl` is at the end it links without issue.

```
gcc source.o -o source -m32 -Xlinker -L/usr/lib -Xlinker -L/usr/lib64 -Xlinker --no-warn-search-mismatch -Xlinker --export-dynamic -lphobos2 -lpthread -lm -lrt -lcurl
```

I'm still curious if there is a way to fix this without manually running the linker.

Comment: There was a change to ld or gcc such that argument order for linking mattered, something about dependencies. Had a pretty good explanation, but just seems to cause problems like this.

Comment: Yep, you can do: `dmd source.d -L-lphobos2 -L-lcurl` to fix the linker order.

Answer (score 5):

As you yourself discovered, the order of libraries is incorrect. A quote from *"An Introduction to GCC"*: *"A library which calls an external function defined in another library should appear before the library containing the function."* In your case `libphobos` calls external library's (libcurl) function(s), so I guess `libphobos` should go before `libcurl`.

The book is available online. Chapter related to the OT is here: http://www.network-theory.co.uk/docs/gccintro/gccintro_18.html

Answer (score 5):

The DMD compiler is clearly broken in this respect. I published a patch to fix it (maybe not the best) but the maintainer of the compiler is not convinced this needs to be fixed at all so there is no much discussion about it.

- https://github.com/D-Programming-Language/dmd/pull/497
- http://d.puremagic.com/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=7044

Comment: Voted for it on Bugzilla and posted support for it on GitHub.  It currently fails the autotester though. The autotester was having trouble recently though so it may be due to something broken in HEAD.

Comment: It might be the patch, it was done for D1 and the autotester only tests D2. Should be trivial to adapt, I never done it because of the lack of interest in merging it, but I'll be happy to do so if the interest is there.

Comment: In case you didn't see it, [here's a discussion](http://forum.dlang.org/thread/mailman.1605.1334108859.4860.digitalmars-d@puremagic.com) about the issue I had from the newsgroup.

Comment: This should be implemented because as it is `std.net.curl` is useless on Linux without being able to control the ordering of linker parameters.

Answer (score 3):

Seemingly the simplest way to fix the phobos2/curl linker order problem, as mentioned elsewhere in this thread:

```
dmd source.d -L-lphobos2 -L-lcurl
```

Works like a charm for me.